# Объединить 3 Observable<Response> в 1

Tags: android, kotlin

делаю N запросов с помощью Retrofit

```
val observables:MutableList<Observable<Response>> = mutableListOf()
 groupIds:List<Int> = listOf(1,2,3)

 groupIds.forEach { i: Int -> observables.add(retrofit.create(VKDataRepo::class.java)
             .dataResponse(i)
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
             .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
```

вот метод dataResponse

```
    @GET("wall.get")
  fun dataResponse(@Query("owner_id") ownerIs: Int): Observable<Response>
```

добавляю их все в observables

Вопрос: Как мне `observables:MuttableList<Observable<Response>>` объединить в один  `Observable<Response>`

P.S. пробовал Observable.zip `val zip: Observable<List<Response>> = zip(observables,{t: Array<out Any> -> (t as Array<Response>).toList() })`
но говорит `java.lang.ClassCastException`

Comment: Мне, как человеку далекому от `Rx`, ваш вопрос звучит так: "Как получит один\первый элемент из списка". Элементарно :)
Наверное, вам лучше перефразировать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зачем вам список с объектами ретрофита для выполнения запросов?

Что бы сделать N запросов и дождаться их завершения хватит и одного объекта ретрофита. Это можно сделать примерно так(**ПСЕВДОКОД**):

```
val client = retrofit.create(VKDataRepo::class.java)
Observable.fromIterable(groupIds)
    .flatMap(id -> client.dataResponse(i))
    .toList() <- дождется завершения всех операций выше, сложит их в список и передаст дальше
    .subscibe(list -> {/* do handle */}) <- сюда прийдет список с ответами List<Response>
```